# How to conver rich:calender date to mysql Date

Tags: java, mysql, richfaces

I am trying to convert rich:calendar date to mysql Date.

and in handler empDOJ is of Date type.when i try to convert it through SimpleDateFormat it is not converting.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date conDate=sdf.parse("doj");
```

Comment: sdf.parse() method needs to a String type argument, the format of the string should be like "yyyy/mm/dd".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date conDate=sdf.parse(doj);
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date conDate=sdf.parse("doj");
```

`mm` indicates `Minutes`
`MM` indicates `Month`